# How do I make ActiveRecord timestamps return a long as created_at and updated_at?

Tags: activerecord, format, timestamp

Currently my timestamps return this in json

`"created_at": "2015-08-16T19:25:37.678Z",
"updated_at": "2015-08-16T19:25:37.678Z",`

And I'd rather a UNIX timestamp GMT 0 like:
7918273981723 (not the actual number :P)

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

`created_at` and `updated_at` both respond to `to_i` to return UNIX time:

```
created_at_unix_time = User.find_by(id: 1).created_at.to_i
```

Comment: Then I need to do .to_i for every endpoint I want to return these at?  I was hoping to be able to do it at an object level.

Comment: So that when I do User.find_by(id: 1) that user gets returned and the created_at is already a unix timestamp

Comment: Rails expects `created_at` and `updated_at` to be of the class type `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. I recommend making a method in the model that returns the values serialized to the format that you expect.